# Is a python processed pinned to one CPU, or can it uses multiple CPU overtime?

Tags: python, processor, gil

So I know that even multithreaded python process can not use multiple core at the same time.
But, by default, does that mean a python process is "pinned" to one CPU?  By pinned, I mean, will the python process use always the same CPU, or can the same process, use **overtime** the different CPU of my machine?

Comment: That's OS specific.  OSes will generally migrate processes around CPUs as it sees fit.

Comment: I've never heard of a OS that does automatic pinning -- it'd be a very silly thing to do, because you'd be wasting resources: Let's say you start 10 processes, then exit all the ones that were randomly assigned to CPU 2. Is CPU 1 now going to be at 100% and CPU 2 going to be at 0%? That's silly.

Comment: Further, some have special commands you can use to set CPU affinity, to pin it to a specific CPU.  Eg: https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/start-an-application-assigned-to-a-specific-cpu-in-windows-vista/

Comment: ...anyhow, there's nothing whatsoever about this that's specific to Python, **or** to the GIL. The GIL stops you from using multiple CPUs *at the same time* (for operations for which it needs to be held). Pinning is about not being moved between CPUs, which is completely unrelated to how many CPUs you're using *simultaneously*.

Comment: This is not a python question.  It depends entirely on the OS scheduler implementation.  On Linux, you would use `taskset` to specify the core or cores to be used by your process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, a python process is not pinned to a particular CPU core.  In fact, despite the GIL, a single python process can spawn multiple threads -- each of which can be scheduled simultaneously by the OS on different CPU cores.  Although the GIL makes it difficult for more than one thread to actually make progress at any given time (since they must all contend for the lock), even this can happen (native code can release the GIL unless / until it needs to access Python datastructures).

You can, of course, use your operating system utilities to pin any process (including Python) to a specific CPU core.